# Можно ли через ВК API для attachments использовать json код?

Tags: vkontakte-api, api

Хочу сделать на питоне программу, которая будет с определенных групп брать посты и выставлять их на моей группе. Вопрос такой, можно ли attachments (то бишь вложения) писать в get запросе json код. Потому что в документации Вк API, я только нашел, что можно сделать так: Поле attachments представляется в формате:
<owner_id>_<media_id>,<owner_id>_<media_id>.

А я бы хотел в формате:

```
"attachments": [
          {
            "type": "photo",
            "photo": {
              "album_id": -7,
              "date": 1597146568,
              "id": 457240371,
              "owner_id": -154625437,
              "has_tags": false,
              "access_key": "381ee183af835ee6ee",
              "post_id": 1144,
              "sizes": [
                {
                  "height": 130,
                  "url": "https://sun3-10.userapi.com/iFNpL-bfGgHKV-wFjvu7M8imjoXhvQKDB878ag/0eFAv08anlk.jpg",
                  "type": "m",
                  "width": 130
                },
                {
                  "height": 130,
                  "url": "https://sun3-10.userapi.com/iFNpL-bfGgHKV-wFjvu7M8imjoXhvQKDB878ag/0eFAv08anlk.jpg",
                  "type": "o",
                  "width": 130
                },
                {
                  "height": 200,
                  "url": "https://sun3-13.userapi.com/KsYE0AVQCd1l-8s7mt-9hDGPqr9hv3SNWcnamg/CSodgriKV-Y.jpg",
                  "type": "p",
                  "width": 200
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так нельзя, уж увы. Но вы могли бы просто брать нужные параметры из этого json'a, а после собирать из них строку в формате <owner_id><media_id>,<owner_id><media_id>.

Примерно так:

```
tmp = []
for el in _json["attachments"]:
    tmp.append(str(el["photo"]["owner_id"]) + "_" + str(el["photo"]["id"]))
out = tmp.join(",")
```

За гавнокод прошу прощения.

Comment: Понял, благодарю за ответ